# Python: Reading a hex number from JSON and passing to a library

Tags: python, json, hex

When I assign variable like `hex_no = 0x67` and pass this over to the library that I want, it works fine.  However, if I retrieve 0x67 from a JSON file, its type is a string and I don't know how to change it to a the same format as this line does `hex_no = 0x67`.  When reading from json, how do i get it into the same format?

This is sample of the json file

{
    "measurement"  : "pressure",
    "i2c_address" : "0x67",
    "device_type": "N"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `0x67` or any other hexadecimal number to that library that you want, you're actually passing an integer. You can check this by doing:

```
>>> type(0x67)
<class 'int'>
```

Therefore, what you need is to convert the hexadecimal representation of that number (i.e, the string), to the integer number per se. You can do it by using the `int` class, passing 16 as the `base` argument to its constructor.

```
num = int('0x67', 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
int(hex_no, 16)
```

See the docs for [int](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) and its base argument.

If you wanted it as a string, wrap it in [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=int#hex).

Comment: But `hex()` returns a string, and that's precisely what OP doesn't want. I think it should be enough with `int(hex_no, 16)`, which returns an integer (same thing as, e.g `0x67`)

Comment: @revliscano you're right, I misread OP and have updated my answer, thanks!